# What impact does air have on our weight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, weight

Although air is light, it is fluid. So it must exert upthrust on people. So does it mean, in fact, we are heavier than our weight? Also, the gravitational acceleration is bigger than its value?

Comment: It's worth to mention that atmospheric pressure of 1 atm gives about $1~\text{kN}$ force on human head.

Answer (score 35):

A human at sea level on Earth will experience a buoyant force equal to the volume of their body times the density of air, pointing upward against gravity. This works out to about 75 grams for an average human weighing about 62 kilograms- a small amount.

Also please note that as a recovering ex-engineer, I interchange mass and force units with easy unconcern- as I consider such trifles to be mere trifles.

Comment: Upvoted, but I was hoping the answer would start by saying “Consider a spherical human.” ;-)

Comment: @EdV, Cows are a better example in this case, because cows displace more air.

Comment: And the upthrust will also depend on the temperature, cold air is denser. Also humidity!

Comment: @JuanPerez yes yes of course, but minor corrections to a small quantity!

Comment: Grams and kilograms are mass. Weight is a force, with newtons as the SI unit.

Comment: While the joke may be amusing to people who understand it, it's needlessly confusing for people who don't. This question is of a basic enough level that spherical cow jokes are probably just confusing to most of the people who would learn something from the answer.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, see my edit, and Ed V's response.  Please note that if I can make someone's day with a light-hearted aside here, then I consider my hard work to be done. I will be glad to explain the joke to anyone who is confused by it and I do not consider it to be smart-assed in any way. -Niels

Comment: As a chemical engineer, married to a chemical engineer who begat a 3rd chemical engineer daughter, I live in house full of folks who took Heat Transfer.  Whenever we put a roast in the oven, someone will likely mention that it's an infinitely long cylindrical roast in an infinitely long rectangular oven.  My son-in-law (with a PhD in American History) no longer asks about that roast after having heard about it so many times.

Comment: For everyone else who is curious about the spherical cow joke: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow

Comment: Perhaps an interesting note: if we imagine a person standing on a scale on Earth or in a vaccum, the weight reduction due to buoyancy will be more than compensated by the absence of the weight of the column of air above the scales.

Comment: Looks like the spherical human opening got deleted first, but so long, and thanks for all the fish!

Comment: @JordiVermeulen the weight of the column of air above the scale is irrelevant. The scale will necessarily be zeroed while that weight is acting upon it (though most scales have a near-identical surface area on the underside of their load platform so it's more likely to be a second net buoyant force). The air pressure that the person eliminates from this zero state over the contact area with the scale is equal to the pressure that the scale eliminates from what the person experiences in free-air buoyancy. So the change in force on the scale is still equal to weight minus displaced air weight.

Comment: 75 grams is hardly small - it's the weight of a typical computer mouse.

Comment: @fattie- it is small, compared to your average spherical human.

Comment: Possibly another question, but how would altitude or air density in a hyperbaric chamber factor in?  How would the magnitudes of the "buoyancy"  compare to changes in gravity at altitude (presumed to be v. small). Would a (very cold) human float in liquid air?

Answer (score 9):

Yes we would be heavier (weigh more on a scale) if we were in a vacuum than atmospheric air, but it would be very little because the density of air (about 1.29 kg/m$^3$) is much less than that of the human, which is approximately that of water (1000 kg/m$^3$).

For air density of 1.29 kg/m$^3$, a 75 kg human body of volume 0.075 m$^3$, the buoyant force is

$F=\rho g V$= (1.29 kg/m$^3$)(9.8 m/s$^2$)(0.075 m$^3$)= 0.95 N=1 N

Making the weight of the person 1 N (= 0.1 kg), or 0.13 percent, more than the scale reading of the person.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We would be heavier in vaccum than our atmosphere.
I don't understand how are you measuring that acceleration.
If you are doing it by calculating g from equation $Gm_1×m_2/m^2 r^2 $
then,
Gravitaional value is not bigger. In normal by saying weight we mean force. The mass is same all the time.  That's why gravitational acceleration will remain same while the actual acceleration due to factor like atmosphere will change.